# If line has no width, we couldn't understand difference of a curved line and straight line if we could see from its perspective, right?

Tags: geometry

I am thinking about points and lines, how they form etc and i just thought this logic. if my intuition is correct, it is absurd to talk about curve of a line in 1 dimension. I wonder if that is correct. Thanks in advance

Comment: For something to be able to curve, it has to exist in more than 1 dimension.

Comment: This is correct and has to do with the idea that there is no intrinsic curvature on a smooth curve.  However, extrinsic curvature can still show a curve bending and twisting within a higher dimensional space.